# Exclude filetypes in a Textmate project

Tags: macos, mac, regex, textmate

I know in TextMate I can go to preferences -> advanced -> folder references and play with the regex pattern to remove certain types of files and folders by default.

I heard that if you have an existing project, however, and chance these, the project is not affected.

From a similar but different angle, I am interested to know if I can exclude certain types of files, say anything named "index.html" from an existing project while not changing the global scope.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change the folder reference exclude patterns

Select the folder reference in the drawer/sidebar, click the "i" (information) button located at the bottom of the drawer/sidebar, and edit the pattern, like you would in TextMate's global preferences.

You can only edit a single folder reference at a time, so you'd need to copy/paste your exclusion rules to all top-level folders if you wanted this to apply project-wide.

This is how you'd exclude all *index.html* files, by setting a proper exclusion rule.

---

Alternatively:

### Remove a file from a project

Right-click the file in the drawer/sidebar, select *Remove Selected Files…* then click *Delete References*.

Do this for all files you want to remove.

The *Go to File…* command (`Cmd-T`) might help you with finding all of these files by name.

Comment: @cwd Is there a reason, other than not being a paying customer, to run a TextMate version that is more than three months old?

Comment: I am using the most up to date version but your text was not consistent with the ux. I assume you have either mistyped it or are using an older version.